# Django Tastypie Authentication for prepend_urls methods

Tags: django, tastypie

My application has several user types admin, user and manager.

I have defined an endpoint for a Resource, which has several prepend_urls.
eg: the endpoints would be

```
/Profile/search/
/Profile/shortview/
/Profile/
```

How can I limit access to the endpoints such that

```
/Profile/search/ is accessible to admin, manager
/Profile/shortview/ is accessible to all
/Profile/ is accessible to admin only
```

I have thought of using my own class but for authentication and authorization but think they are applied to the entire resource not individual prepend_url endpoints.

```
authorization = MyAuthorization()
authentication= MyAuthentication()
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suppose you have been configured your `prepend_urls` and hence you have wrapped a function called `dispatch_search`, so something like this will raise an exception if user is unauthorized to use the endpoint:

```
def dispatch_search(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # check authorization here
    self._meta.authorization.is_authorized(request)
```

**Edited from here below**

When inheriting from the DjangoAuthorization class, you also can override the methods:

- read_detail(self, object_list, bundle)
- read_list(self, object_list, bundle)

to raise an exception if user should not be able to read an specific resource or the resource list itself.

And your MyAuthorization class:

```
from tastypie.exceptions import Unauthorized
from tastypie.authorization import DjangoAuthorization

class MyAuthorization(DjangoAuthorization):
    def is_authorized(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser and 'search' in request.path:
            return True
        # more business logic here to check the other endpoints
        raise Unauthorized('Unauthorized :(')

    def read_list(self, object_list, bundle):
        self.is_authorized(bundle.request)  # call your custom validation
        # Fallback to the DjangoAuthorization read_list
        return super(MyAuthorization, self).read_list(object_list, bundle)
```

Refer to the docs for a complete list of functions you can override to add more business logic: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html#the-authorization-api

Comment: `from tastypie.exceptions import Unauthorized
class CustomAuthorization(DjangoAuthorization):
    def is_authorized(self, request):
        raise Unauthorized('Unauthorized :(')`  `            authorization = CustomAuthorization()
            authentication=CustomBasicAuthentication()` This is my code, I think this should always raise an exception but my API's can be accessed without error

Comment: Have you added this: `self._meta.authorization.is_authorized(request)` in the wrapped view?

Comment: Right, that worked for all the wrapped views but my main endpoint still has full access. eg:- /profile/search/ throws Unauthorized but /profile/ does not

Comment: `is_authorized` is no longer a part of tastypie, could you please update this answer to prevent any confusion? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry @SeánHayes, I agree with you but I didn't say that.